# Imprimir una matriz dejando espacio entre los valores

Tags: java

quiero imprimir una matriz y quiero dejar espacios entre los valores que se muestran

```
public class AH2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Declaramos un array de dos dimensiones con un tamaño de 3 en la
    // primera dimensión y diferentes tamaños en la segunda

    int miArray[][] = new int[4][];
    // No especificamos el tamaño de la segunda dimensión
    miArray[0] = new int[4]; // El tamaño de la segunda dimensión es 4
    miArray[1] = new int[4]; // El tamaño de la segunda dimensión es 4
    miArray[2] = new int[4]; // El tamaño de la segunda dimensión es 4
    miArray[3] = new int[4]; // El tamaño de la segunda dimensión es 4

    // Rellenamos el array con datos

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < miArray[i].length; j++)

            miArray[i][j] = i*j;


    }
    // Visualizamos los datos que contiene el array

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < miArray[i].length; j++)

            System.out.print(miArray[i][j] + "  ");
        System.out.println("\n ");

    }


}

}
```

Gracias

Anexo mi código,,,, ya con la respuesta dada,,,

Comment: Comparte con todos lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir una matriz tienes que hacer un doble loop.

Para dejar un espacio es simplemente concatenar el valor que imprimes con un espacio (+" "). La mayor complejidad es recorrer la matriz.

Por matriz entiendo que es un array de 2 dimensiones, pongamos que es de (int), de números enteros de 32 bits.

```
private int[][] matriz;
private int filas = 5, columnas = 6;
// supongamos que ya está inicializada

for(int i=0; i < filas; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < columnas; j++)
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Con esto debería bastar para imprimir tu matriz. Es importante que sepas loopear sobre la matriz, es la base de cualquier operación sobre ella ;)

Comment: Por favor, evitemos hacer el trabajo de los demás. La filosofía de esta comunidad es ayudar a resolver los problemas de cualquiera, siempre y cuando demuestren que lo han intentado, que han investigado y que siguen teniendo problemas. Saludos

Comment: listo gracias,, era lo único porque ya podía recorrer la matriz que era de columnas variables

Comment: ¿Qué rayos es _loopear_?